# How to play files with obscured file names?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am making an app that downloads videos to the documents directory and plays them with MPMoviePlayerController. To help prevent the videos from being taken off of the device and played, I am going to obfuscate the file names. Let's say I want to play a movie marked "movie.blah" when the real file extension is "mov". How do I get this to play? Do I have to temporarily rename it to "movie.mov" and then change it back when it is done playing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Bad way to go. Obfuscation for security is the equivalent of using saran wrap for clothes - everything's still visible. Use a handler script to decide whether the file can be served up or not, and provide acess to your movie ONLY via this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc B indicated, you do not want to use obfuscation for security.  Here's an approach that would work.  The overhead is minimal (28 bytes).

1. Define your own wrapper file format that can embed a standard .mov file.  It can be very simple with a fixed length header and a parameter indicating the length of the embedded movie file.
2. In your custom file format, encrypt the data stream using AES and a unique key from the device hardware (CPU serial number perhaps).
3. During playback simply decode the file to an in-memory buffer as-needed.  You should be able to support partial decryption and immediate playback.

This way users will have to both copy the file and determine what you used for the encryption key in order to play the file back on another device.

Layout Example:

```
------------------
MOV Wrapper Header
4 bytes:  File Type Header ID Magic: "MWHF"
16 bytes: Encryption Algorithm: "AES256"
8 bytes:  64-bit unsigned file length
------------------
Embedded and encrypted mov file
```

The key to securing the file will be the choice of the encryption key.  You don't want to use a static key and you don't want to use a key that is accessible outside of the device.

This question may help with finding a suitable uuid: [iPhone / iPad user profile tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183541/iphone-ipad-user-profile-tracking)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Will. I'm going to look into encryption.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the video in a directory that doesn't get backed up when you sync with iTunes? I think Library/Caches qualifies.

Comment: Does Apple have any policies about clearing that directory when disk space is needed?  Seems like a 'cache' would be a good candidate for eviction when you need disk space...

Comment: As I recall, if the device runs out of disk space, iOS deletes files in Caches. Big video files that can be downloaded again would seem like likely candidates for deletion when disk space runs short.